# Remove null from SOLR Indexes

Tags: solr

I am currently indexing a few documents from an external source into SOLR. This external source has few empty elements that are getting indexed in SOLR as well. How can I avoid indexing empty/null values in SOLR.

For e.g.

My CSV is  **name,city,zip**. Some values are

```
Jack,Houston, 89812
,Austin,98123
```

In the second value set I do not have a name. However, when SOLR indexes this document it adds {"Name":"","City":"Austin","Zip":"98123"}. How can I avoid having "Name" as an empty element in SOLR?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to your comment below - this CSV file isn't submitted directly to Solr as a CSV file? Solr will _by default_ ignore any field with an empty value in a csv file, unless you explicitly tell it it to keep it with `keepEmpty`.

Comment: My apologies. I should have mentioned the usage of Spark to convert the CSV to JSON and then index it to SOLR. Can you please shed some light on keepEmpty? Where do I set this? Is it a SOLR property?

Comment: [`keepEmpty` is an argument you can give the CSV update module](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVUpdateParameters), which excludes fields that doesn't have a value in the CSV file. For the same for general updates, see the answer by Alexandre.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do any pre-processing on submitted documents before they hit the schema, Solr has a whole [UpdateRequestProcessor subsystem](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/update-request-processors.html). The specific one you are looking for is *RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory*, possibly coupled with *TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory*. there

Remember that you need to tell Solr that you want to use them, either via chain (default or explicit) or via individual configuration (explicit), all described in the first link above.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your CSV to JSON, not providing the empty name and then indexing the JSON file(s).

Solr by itself only indexes what it gets. If it indexes an empty field, it got an empty field. And this is what happens with the CSV indexer, I guess, it just is not made to leave empty fields out.

With JSON *you* are in control.

Comment: That was my last resort. I am picking a huge CSV file into a Spark Data Frame and then indexing it directly to SOLR. I will have to code something in Spark while creating the JSON. I thought there would be a better approach within the managed-schema to drop elements that are empty/null. For e.g. Check the length of the field. If greater than zero index it or else don't add it to the document.